# Can I call a method of a base object without casting it?

Tags: c#, object

EDIT. I'm sorry for the typo.  Both objects are independent.  OBJ1 is actually from a 3rd party and i have no access to its constructor so I built my own with some of its functionality and some of my own.

I have a method which will be called using OBJ1 as a parameter.
I have a need to write the exact same routine but passing OBJ2 as a paramater.
OBJ1 and OBJ2 are not identical but they do have a property in common: Prop1.

Details: OBJ1 is a 3rd party object with no public constructor so for testing, I created my own object which is "similar" but in no way identical to the original.  They have some properties in common including: Prop1.

I'd like to do this:

```
   private ObjectTypeA OBJ1 = new ObjectTypeA();
   private ObjectTypeB OBJ2 = new ObjectTypeB();
   main() 
   {
        GetPlacedOrderIDFromTag(OBJ1);
        GetPlacedOrderIDFromTag(OBJ2);

   }
   private void FunctionA (object _obj)
    {
        // I know this object has this property.  
         _obj.Prop1 = true;
    }
```

I tried implementing a partial interface like this: 
        
`private  partial interface IOrderUserTag { bool Prop1 { get; set;  } }`

but since OBJ1 is a 3rd party object, I cannot get the compiler to know that it adheres to this interface.

'Would love an idea for not having duplicate code I need to maintain.

Thanks,
-Ed

Comment: Might want to check out the adapter pattern as a potentially more maintainable solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 2):

C# does provide duck typing -- the `dynamic` keyword:

```
((dynamic)_obj).Prop1 = true;
```

That will work as long as `_obj` has a boolean setter called `Prop1` (casing matters).

The other way to do it is to drop down to reflection level, it provides functions to search up and down the list of properties and you can call them with your own parameters.

Comment: Thank you... but that did not seem to work.   Compile cannot resolve _obj.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, `_obj` is fully defined in your function (it is a parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Reflection way of doing it:

```
    public void DoStuff(object obj)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Prop1");

        if (prop != null && prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool) && prop.CanWrite)
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, true);
        }
    }
```

You can put in whatever checks you feel necessary into the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Only if this applies, you just need to call same routines with different objects?

```
public void FunctionA<T>(T obj)
{
  //obj.GetType().GetProperty("Prop1").SetValue(obj, true, null); 
}
```

Comment: How does the type `T` know that it has a property `Prop1` ?

Comment: He needs to set Prop1=true,  `obj.GetType().GetProperty("Prop1").SetValue(obj, true, null); `

Comment: What if an object that does not have a `Prop1` property gets passed into the method?

Comment: Firstly, OP said both objects have `Prop1` but one should first check if `GetProperty("Prop1")` doesnt returns a null.